# Cordova DatePicker for WP8

Tags: cordova, windows-phone-8, cordova-plugins

I am unable to use the [DatePicker](https://github.com/VitaliiBlagodir/cordova-plugin-datepicker) plugin for WP8 as it is not supported. Is there any option/alternative for showing a datePicker and timePicker for WP8 in the Cordova project?

This [alternative](https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-datetime-picker) does not build using the CLI, neither does [this](https://github.com/hypermurea/phonegap-wp8-datepicker-plugin) as it gives the error:

[image: error]

Comment: try input type date or time without using any other plugin will open native date and time picker..  **<input type="time">** and **<input type="date">**

Comment: This doesn't work, it shows a text box into which characters can be entered.

Comment: try **http://phonegap-plugins.com/plugins/hypermurea/phonegap-wp8-datepicker-plugin**

Comment: or https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-datetime-picker

Comment: I have tried both of these, the first one does not add to the project and the second one does not build.

Comment: what's error at time of build for second one?

Comment: The issue is here: https://github.com/leecrossley/cordova-plugin-datetime-picker/issues/6

Comment: did you try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23242060/invoking-date-time-picker-plugin-in-windows-phone-8 ?